# Fabric prints a new line for every bit of Git progress

Tags: fabric

I've got Fabric set up to `git fetch` on a remote machine. It works fine, but there's a new line printed to `stdout` for every percentage progress that Git prints:

```
[host] out: remote: Compressing objects:   1% (3/252)   
[host] out: remote: Compressing objects:   2% (6/252)   
[host] out: remote: Compressing objects:   3% (8/252)   
[host] out: remote: Compressing objects:   4% (11/252)   
[host] out: remote: Compressing objects:   5% (13/252)   
[host] out: remote: Compressing objects:   6% (16/252)   
[host] out: remote: Compressing objects:   7% (18/252)   
[host] out: remote: Compressing objects:   8% (21/252)   
[host] out: remote: Compressing objects:   9% (23/252) 
...
[host] out: Resolving deltas:   0% (0/72)   
[host] out: Resolving deltas:  12% (9/72)   
[host] out: Resolving deltas:  15% (11/72)   
[host] out: Resolving deltas:  18% (13/72)   
[host] out: Resolving deltas:  22% (16/72)   
[host] out: Resolving deltas:  23% (17/72)   
[host] out: Resolving deltas:  55% (40/72)
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
run('git fetch', pty=False)
```

Comment: Nice, this is an interesting approach--thanks. Practically what this does is skips local output of all the `Unpacking objects` and `Resolving deltas` and similar lines from the remote machine, and just prints summary output that follows, such as `8926e73..116683d  master     -> origin/master` and `Updating 8926e73..116683d` and `Fast-forward`. Although this doesn't solve the problem, this is a pretty good middle ground. Could you explain why not allocating a PTY yields this result? I wouldn't have thought of this because I don't understand why this works.

Comment: Some commands like git or apt-get, when they have a PTY, consider that they're being run interactively in a terminal, and can output fancy progress information. Without a PTY, they will often fall back to a non-interactive mode, with simpler output, more suitable for e.g. being piped into another command.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is this if I don't care to see the output of the command:

```
with hide('stdout'):
    run('git fetch')
```